# No cursor in vim

Tags: vim, cmder

UPDATE 16-03-01:

I changed the highlight option to make text dark green, as you can see in the picture.  Notice the cursor is on one of the parenthesis, making them both orange, but there's no cursor:

EDIT (SOLVED):

I just deleted the .vimrc file entirely and now the cursor is back so there was some typo or problem in there that messed with it.

[image]

ORIGINAL:

I don't have any cursor, box or line in vim.  I'm using vim through the latest version of cmder.  I'm new to vim but I couldn't find anyone else with a similar problem.

Comment: Press `Esc` and then `i` to start `insert mode`, then you will be able to inser text. Hope this will help

Comment: enter :e to reload the buffer, and you may find the cursor reappears

Answer (score 3):

You can set `cursorline` using

```
set cursorline
```

in your `~/.vimrc` file. But this looks clumsy with a long line 
and you can remedied by highlighting `cursorline`

```
highlight CursorLine   cterm=NONE ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=darkgreen
```

You can select your own colour, here I have used `darkgreen`.

where `cterm` is terminal colour, set to `NONE`

`ctermbg` back ground color of terminal. also set to `NONE` here

Comment: Weirdly, setting the highlight color to darkgreen makes all the text on the current line green with a black background (so I guess that worked?) but there's still no cursor at all, not a box or a blinking line.

Comment: Can you share your vimrc then

Answer (score 1):

Please add the following to your ~/.vimrc

`set nocompatible
set mouse=a
set cursorline`

In a short, the behavior of VIM is configured by the  ~/.vimrc file, you should add configurations in it for yourself.

Comment: Tried this, still no cursor at all.